# Is it possible to use AppDomain to counter WebBrowser memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control, appdomain

Is it possible to counter WebBrowser memory leak by using it in separate AppDomain and reloading it once in a while to reset used memory?

Comment: What memory leak? Why not fix it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, .NET WebBrowser component leaks memory when navigating between pages, it is a pretty well known issue from what I manage to understand and to what I could not manage to find a definite solution. The only solutions I managed to find is to use it in separate process (I created the question to know if AppDomain can be used instead) and reload it from time to time or use some 3rd party alternative. If there are any other solutions that allow to go around the memory leak - I would be really grateful for them though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebBrowser leaks you're talking about most likely happen in the underlying ActiveX control, which is unmanaged code. AppDomain helps isolate managed code only so cannot be of much help fighting down the leaks under question.

You would have to resort to running the WebBrowser in a separate process should you really suffer such leaks, I'm afraid.